# SQL Join with duplicate row if value in column is more than 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have a two tables. First contains documents and details information and the second holds the position of this documents. I want join this table so that if in table2 the quantity is more than 1 I get that number of row in the results. Example below.

Example.
1 Table:

ID_DOC || NR_DOC || YEAR || DATE      || COUNTRY
 
  123       ||  WZ-20    ||  2015  ||20150129||  PL
 
  124       ||  WZ-22    ||  2015  ||20150128||  DE

2 Table:

ID_PAL || TYPE_P   || QUA || SUMWEIGHT      || ID_DOC
 
  111       ||  EURO    ||  1     ||200                        ||  123
 
  112       ||  EURO    ||  3     ||900                        ||  124

Result:

ID_DOC || NR_DOC|| YEAR || DATE     || COUNTRY || TYPE_P || QUA ||SUMW
 
  123       ||  WZ-20    ||  2015  ||20150129||  PL              || EURO    || 1       ||200
 
  124       ||  WZ-22    ||  2015  ||20150129||  PL              || EURO    || 1       ||300
   124       ||  WZ-22    ||  2015  ||20150129||  PL              || EURO    || 1       ||300
   124       ||  WZ-22    ||  2015  ||20150129||  PL              || EURO    || 1       ||300

It is possible? Thanks for advice.

Comment: what did you try so far? did you try join? did you try inner selects?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I do not think that this is possible.

Comment: Me too but I want ask before I will search for another way ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've assumed that you want the same number of rows in the results as the value in the Qty column, in which case you can do this with a numbers table - a table that contains a single int column populated with a lot of numbers. Then you can do a join like this

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table2] PP 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table1] DD on PP.docid = DD.docid 
INNER JOIN Numbers NN on PP.qty >= NN.n
```

A quick way to create a numbers table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers
(
  n INT PRIMARY KEY
);


INSERT dbo.Numbers(n) 
SELECT TOP (10000) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
 (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]) 
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 
CROSS JOIN sys.objects AS s2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select tbl1.id_doc, tbl1.nr_doc, tbl1.year, tbl1.date, tbl1.country, tbl2.type_p, tbl2.qua.tbl2.sumweight
from doc table1, location table2
where table1.id_doc = table2.id_doc
and (select count(*) from location where id_doc = table2.id_doc ) > 1
```